# Why does phase of a wave change after reflecting from a denser medium?

Tags: waves, reflection, superposition

Why does phase of a wave change when reflected from a denser medium, but no change takes place in phase during transmission?

Comment: No time to write a proper answer now, but think about the common intro physics demos involving waves travelling on a rope.  This is like reflection from a tethered rope end vs reflection from a free rope end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### tl;dr:

It's because of *discontinuous* change in impedance $\rm Z.$

## Reflection Coefficient $\rm R$:

Let the point where two media meet be $z=0\;.$ At $z= 0\,,$ the incident wave is given as $$\psi_\textrm{inc}(0,t)= A\cos\omega t\;.$$

The total force exerted by the *input terminal* of the second medium is given by $$\begin{align}F&= \underbrace{F_\textrm{term}}_\textrm{termination force exerted for termination of the incident wave if the second media had the same impedance as the first one}+ \underbrace{F_\textrm{exc}}_\textrm{excess force exerted due to difference in media}\\ &= -\mathrm Z_1\frac{\partial \psi_\textrm{inc}(0,t)}{\partial t}+ \mathrm Z_1\frac{\partial \psi_\textrm{ref}(0,t)}{\partial t}\tag 1\end{align}$$

But the force is equivalent to the force provided by a damper of the same impedance; then $F$ is given by $$F=-\mathrm Z_2\frac{\partial \psi_\textrm{inc}(0,t)}{\partial t} -\mathrm Z_2\frac{\partial \psi_\textrm{ref}(0,t)}{\partial t}\tag 2$$

Equating $(1)$ and $(2)\,,$ we get

$$\frac{\partial \psi_\textrm{ref}(0,t)}{\partial t}= \underbrace{\left[\frac{\mathrm Z_1- \mathrm Z_2}{\mathrm Z_1+ \mathrm Z_2}\right]}_\textrm{reflection coefficient}\frac{\partial \psi_\textrm{inc}(0,t)}{\partial t}$$

The term in the parenthesis is termed by $\rm R_{12}\,,$ the *reflection coefficient.*

The total displacement $\psi(z,t)$ is given by

\begin{align}\psi(z,t)&= \psi_\textrm{inc}(z,t) + \psi_\textrm{ref}(z,t)\\ &= A\cos(\omega t- k_1z) + \mathrm R_{12}A\cos(\omega t+ k_1z)\tag 3\end{align}

## Transmission coefficient $\rm T$:

Let the transmitted wave be given as $$\psi_\textrm{trans}(z,t)= (\mathrm T\,A)\,\cos(\omega t- k_2z)\tag 4$$

Since, the wavefunction must be *smooth* i.e. continuous at the boundary; equating $(3)$ and $(4)\,$ we get the *amplitude transmission coefficient* $\rm T$ as  $$\rm T= 1+ R \;.$$

> Why does phase of a wave change when reflected from a denser medium, but no change takes place in phase during transmission?

When a wave goes from a medium of lower impedance (that is *low density*) to a medium of higher impedance (that is *high density*) viz. $\rm Z_2 \gt Z_1\,$ then $\rm R_{12}\lt 0$ and that *flips* the sign of the wave.

Also, then $\rm T\in (0, 1)$  and that would mean the transmitted wave has the same sign as that of the incident wave; that is it doesn't *flip*.

### Edit in response to OP's comment:

> why does phase of a wave doesnt change even if its reflected from a rarer medium

Because now, $\rm Z_1\gt Z_2 $ which implies $\rm R_{12}\gt 0$ and thus $\psi_\textrm{ref}(z,t)$ remains same; its phase doesn't change.

Comment: But, why does phase of a wave doesnt change even if its reflected from a rarer medium(i.e back reflection of light wave when passing from optically denser to rarer medium.

Comment: @PrayasAgrawal: Edited. Check now.